# asymptotics of numbers represented by certain indefinite binary quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms

A postdoc wrote to me, asking about   about the asymptotic number of elements  represented integrally by, say, $x^2 - n^3  y^2$  in the set  of numbers $-N$ to $N.$   Actually, he included $x^2 - n^5 y^2$  or any $x^2 - n^p  y^2$ for positive nonsquare $n$  and odd prime $p.$

The only tidbit I know is for the positive form $x^2 + y^2.$   I got to fiddling with the base set  represented by $x^2 - n y^2 ,$  pretending I knew that. Then ran computer simulations for the easiest case, $x^2 - n^3 y^2 = x^2 - n (ny)^2.$ Among other things:  there are new local restrictions: if a prime $q$   divides $n,$  then a number divisible by $q$ but not  $q^2$  is out. Now, when the form class number grows, it is also true that $x^2 - n^3 y^2 $ can't represent all the primes  represented by $x^2 - n y^2.$  I worked the ratio out, $h(4 n^3) = h(4n) \gcd(n,u), $  where $t^2 - n u^2 = 1$ is the fundamental solution. An extreme example with small numbers is $x^2 - 46 y^2$  compared to $x^2 - 46^3 y^2,$  the (form) class number increases by a factor of the same $46$

So, short version, **the Question** is to describe the asymptotics of numbers represented by $x^2 - n^p y^2$

Oh, I asked this a few days ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766281/given-the-numbers-integrally-represented-by-x2-n-y2-what-proportion-are-r

Answer (score 8):

This follows from Bernays' generalization of Landau's theorem, the original reference is this:

P. Bernays,  *Uber die Darstellung von positiven, ganzen Zahlen durch die primitiven,
binaren quadratischen Formen einer nicht quadratischen Diskriminante*.  Ph.D. dissertation, Georg-August-Universitat, Gottingen, Germany, 1912.

In particular it is proved that for any irreducible binary quadratic form $f(x,y)$ there exists a positive number $c_f$ such that the asymptotic formula

$$\displaystyle \# \{|n| \leq X : \exists (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \text{ s.t. } f(x,y) = n\} \sim \frac{c_f X}{\sqrt{\log X}}$$

holds. A modern paper that examines this problem in much more detail is the following paper of Granville and Blomer:

V. Blomer, A. Granvile, *[Estimates for representation numbers of quadratic forms](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-135/issue-2/Estimates-for-representation-numbers-of-quadratic-forms/10.1215/S0012-7094-06-13522-6.short)*, Duke. Math. J. **135** (2006), 261-302.

Comment: That's lovely, Stanley!

Comment: I can see by the Bernays title that he includes indefinite forms. The first few pages of  Blomer-Granville emphasize positive forms, though.  I'll look som e more

Comment: @WillJagy you are right, the Blomer-Granville paper does deal with positive definite forms only.